# Multiple radiobutton in DataGrid (WPF), data not set after changing selection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Binded **4 radio buttons** in a **datagrid**. Items are loading finely while its loading in Grid. But If I change the radio button selection, I am not getting value in datagrid.Itemsource. all itemsource value are same as before. No change found.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vehicle Type" Width="150" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RadioButton Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="None" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.None}}"/>
                                        <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="Small" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.Small}}"/>
                                        <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="Medium" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.Medium}}"/>
                                        <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="Heavy" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.Heavy}}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

---

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FindCriteria" ObjectType="{x:Type src:enumObjectType}" />
    <src:EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="CustomRadioButtonStyle"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">

        <BulletDecorator Background="#00FFFFFF" Height="18">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet >
                <mwt:BulletChrome Height="15" Width="15" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding ButtonBase.IsPressed}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding ToggleButton.IsChecked}" IsRound="True"  />
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <ContentPresenter Height="15" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </BulletDecorator>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ContentControl.HasContent">
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="IFrameworkInputElement">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <ResourceDictionary />
                            </Style.Resources>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Rectangle Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Control.Padding">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Thickness>4,0,0,0</Thickness>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

```
public class EnumMatchToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
            return false;

        string checkValue = value.ToString();
        string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
        return checkValue.Equals(targetValue, 
                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
            return null;

        bool useValue = (bool)value;
        string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
        if (useValue)
            return Enum.Parse(targetType, targetValue);

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ValidObjectVerificationGrid : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
    }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    private enumObjectType objectType;

    public enumObjectType ObjectType
    {
        get { return objectType; }
        set { objectType = value; }
    }
    public string ObjectDetails { get; set; }
    public bool? IsVerified { get; set; }

}

public enum enumObjectType
{ 
    None,
    Small,
    Medium,
    Heavy
}
```

Comment: How is the DataContext for your Grid set?

Comment: @Rachel `ValidObjectVerificationGrid ` this is the datacontext.

Comment: How is it set though? I often see mistakes where the View and ViewModel each have a different copy of the data object.

Comment: A quick copy/paste of your code shows that it does correctly set the property on the object model, so the problem is probably something to do with how your DataContext is set.

Comment: @Rachel Yes, abolutely. But I am stuck at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to make your sourcecode running and try to solve the matter from my end. You have to use **RadioButton_Checked** event in each radio button. and while this event fires, catch the selected item, convert it to your datacontext object , update the selected value and finally reload the datagrid itemssource. Thats it. I hope it will work for you.

Here Is some code, which may work for you:

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ValidObjectVerificationGrid> fullSource = (List<ValidObjectVerificationGrid>dgValidObjectVerification.ItemsSource;
        ValidObjectVerificationGrid x = null;
        int index ;
        try
        {
            x = (ValidObjectVerificationGrid)dgValidObjectVerification.SelectedItem;
            index = dgValidObjectVerification.SelectedIndex;
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        if (x!=null)
        {
            // ... Get RadioButton reference.
            var button = sender as RadioButton;

            // ... Display button content as title.
            this.Title = button.Content.ToString();


            if ((Boolean)button.IsChecked)
            {
                x.ObjectType = (enumObjectType)Enum.Parse(typeof(enumObjectType), button.Content.ToString(), true);
            }
            foreach (ValidObjectVerificationGrid tmp in fullSource)
            {
                if (tmp.Count == x.Count)
                    tmp.ObjectType = x.ObjectType;
            }
            dgValidObjectVerification.ItemsSource = null;
            dgValidObjectVerification.ItemsSource = fullSource;

        }
    }
```

And here is your XAML Radio button part:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="None" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
                                    Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.None}}"/>
                                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="Small" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
                                    Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.Small}}"/>
                                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="Medium" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
                                    Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.Medium}}"/>
                                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomRadioButtonStyle}" Content="Heavy" FontSize="8" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
                                    Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static src:enumObjectType.Heavy}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Visual Studio on this machine but I noticed your setters in ValidObjectVerificationGrid never call your OnPropertyChanged method.

Try this:

```
public enumObjectType ObjectType
    {
        get { return objectType; }
        set
        {
            objectType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ObjectType"));

        }
    }
```

You should be calling OnPropertyChanged for each property such as ObjectDetails and IsVerified etc...

Comment: While radio button selection is being changed, property change event is not triggering.  How to do this?

Comment: I can't see all your code but somewhere you must set your DataContext to your code behind file or ViewModel however you are doing it. In code behind in the constructor you can add DataContext=this;